# rembg library can't open 'i' error and also pickling error

Tags: python

I want to use rembg library to remove background of images. So I followed the instructions on github and try with rembg cli:

Python version: 3.9.12

rembg version: 1.0.27

OS: macOS Monterey 12.4

Chip: Apple M1 Silicon

https://github.com/danielgatis/rembg

```
rembg i man.jpeg output.png
```

Even if I'm on the right directory, I got this error message:

```
rembg: error: argument input: can't open 'i': [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'i'
```

How can I resolve this? Is there any other methods?

Here is my other trial:

```
from rembg.bg import remove
from PIL import Image

input_path = 'man.jpeg'
output_path = 'output.png'

input = Image.open(input_path)
output = remove(input)
output.save(output_path)
```

It also gives that error message:

```
  File "/Users/cucal/Desktop/coding/venvs/science/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/serialization.py", line 920, in _legacy_load
    magic_number = pickle_module.load(f, **pickle_load_args)
_pickle.UnpicklingError: invalid load key, '<'.
```

**Edit:**
I tried this one https://github.com/danielgatis/rembg/issues/262 , but I don't know how to handle downloaded files. One is '.pth' other is '.onnx' files. When I copy these files to u2net in site-package, I'm getting the same pickle error.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps it does not work with jpeg (only png)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33497021)